# Is this the good way to handle multiple formsets in the same view?

Tags: python, django, formset

First I'm using Python 3.7.3 and Django 2.2

I am encountering a problem for handling multiple formsets in the same view. In my view, I'm creating my formsets in a for loop (check down below) and then I'm adding them in a list. In my template I do a for loop on that list and display the formset in the template. I think that what I've done works well but something wrong happens when a formset is not valid (because I did some validation too). When a formset is not valid (because values are not accepted), the other formsets are initilized with those values too. Why ?

**`models.py`**

```
class Set(models.Model):
    timeSet     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    scoreTeam1  = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    scoreTeam2  = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    match       = models.ForeignKey(Match, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Match(models.Model):
    isFinished  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team1Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team2Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phase       = models.ForeignKey(Phase, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teams       = models.ManyToManyField(Team, default=None, blank=True)
```

**`tournament_manage_phase_matches.html`**

```
{% for match in matches %}
                    {% if match.teams.first.pool == pool %}
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            {% if match.isFinished == False %}
                                <div class="btn-group dropright">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                        Field number : {{ pool.field.numField }} | {{ match.teams.first.name }} VS {{ match.teams.last.name }}
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropright</span>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        {% for formset_set in list_formset_set %}
                                            {% if formset_set.match == match %}
                                                <form class="px-4 py-3" method="post">
                                                {% csrf_token %}
                                                    {{ formset_set|crispy }}
                                                    {{ formset_set.management_form }}
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ match.pk }}" name="match_pk">Save score</button>
                                                </form>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {% else %}
                                {% if match.team1Win == False and match.team2Win == False %}
                                    <label>{{ match.teams.first.name }} VS {{ match.teams.last.name }} : Match nul</label>
                                {% else %}
                                    {% if match.team1Win == True and match.team2Win == False %}
                                        <label>{{ match.teams.first.name }} VS {{ match.teams.last.name }} : Victory {{ match.teams.first.name }}</label>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if match.team1Win == False and match.team2Win == True %}
                                        <label>{{ match.teams.first.name }} VS {{ match.teams.last.name }} : Victory {{ match.teams.last.name }}</label>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

So to recap, when I submit a formset, if it's not valid, all other formsets become like the formset that I just submit, and I don't understand why.
If you see something wrong in what I did please tell me too :)

Edit: 
**`views.py`**

```
...
#creation of forms
    list_formset_set = []
    for match in matches:
        if match.isFinished == False:
            formset_set = MatchSetFormset(request.POST or None, instance=match, prefix="form-" + str(match.pk) + "-match")
            formset_set.match = match
            list_formset_set.append(formset_set)

    for formset_set in list_formset_set:
        id_match_submit = request.POST.get("match_pk")
        str_id_match_formet_set = str(formset_set.match.pk)
        if id_match_submit == str_id_match_formet_set:
            if formset_set.is_valid():
                formset_set.save()
                nb_set_winner_t1 = 0
                nb_set_winner_t2 = 0
                for set_match in formset_set:
                    if set_match.cleaned_data.get('scoreTeam1') == set_match.cleaned_data.get('scoreTeam2'):
                        nb_set_winner_t1 += 0
                        nb_set_winner_t2 -= 0
                    else:
                        if set_match.cleaned_data.get('scoreTeam1') > set_match.cleaned_data.get('scoreTeam2'):
                            nb_set_winner_t1 += 1
                            nb_set_winner_t2 -= 1
                        else:
                            nb_set_winner_t1 -= 1
                            nb_set_winner_t2 += 1   

                match = formset_set.cleaned_data[0].get('match')
                team1 = formset_set.cleaned_data[0].get('match').teams.first()
                team2 = formset_set.cleaned_data[0].get('match').teams.last()
                if nb_set_winner_t1 == nb_set_winner_t2:
                    team1.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerDraw
                    team2.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerDraw
                    team1.save()
                    team2.save()
                    match.isFinished = True
                    match.save()
                else:
                    if nb_set_winner_t1 > nb_set_winner_t2:
                        team1.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerVictory
                        team1.nbVictory += 1
                        team2.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerDefeat
                        team2.nbDefeat += 1
                        team1.save()
                        team2.save()
                        match.team1Win = True
                        match.isFinished = True
                        match.save()
                    else:
                        team1.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerDefeat
                        team1.nbDefeat += 1
                        team2.totalpoints += sport.nbPointPerVictory
                        team2.nbVictory += 1
                        team1.save()
                        team2.save()
                        match.team2Win = True
                        match.isFinished = True
                        match.save()
                teams = Team.objects.filter(pool__in=pools).order_by('-totalpoints') #"-" means descending
                for index, team in enumerate(teams):
                    team.position = index + 1
                return redirect('matches_phase_manage_tournament', id=id, id_phase=id_phase)
            else:
                # reload formsets
                print("invalid")
```

> Environment:
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tournament/admin-1/manage-phase/30-matches/
>   Django Version: 2.2
>   Python Version: 3.7.3
>   Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',
>    'django.contrib.auth',
>    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>    'django.contrib.sessions',
>    'django.contrib.messages',
>    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
>    'crispy_forms',
>    'categories',
>    'matches',
>    'phases',
>    'pools',
>    'rules',
>    'sets',
>    'sports',
>    'teams',
>    'tournaments',
>    'pages',
>    'gymnasiums',
>    'fields']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>   Traceback:
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\src\pages\views.py" in matches_phase_view
>     370.                  print(formset)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in 
>     388.     klass.**str** = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in **str**
>     64.         return self.as_table()
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in as_table
>     404.         forms = ' '.join(form.as_table() for form in self)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in **iter**
>     68.         return iter(self.forms)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in **get**
>     80.         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in forms
>     136.                  for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in total_form_count
>     110.             return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in **get**
>     80.         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>   File "C:\Users\33643\Documents\Projets Django\TournamentManagerApp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in management_form
>     92.                     code='missing_management_form',
>   Exception Type: ValidationError at /tournament/admin-1/manage-phase/30-matches/
>   Exception Value: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Comment: It depends on you! Just follow the `>>> import this`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sur if I understood your answer

Comment: Run `import this` in python shell can show the zen of python. Documentation of Django is pretty: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I already looked this documentation and I didn't saw how we can handle multiple formsets in the same view

Comment: the problem is that all your formsets have the same prefix. Look at the generated HTML (in your browser) and you'll see that multiple input fields have the same `name` attribute. So in your loop, you need to [add a prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#customizing-a-formset-s-prefix) to each formset that changes each iteration. You add the prefix by passing the `prefix` argument to your formset initialiser.

Comment: another issue I see is that you exit the for loop as soon as one formset is valid (`return redirect`) without even doing anything with the submitted data. Is that what you really intend?

Comment: And here's the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#multiple-formsets-in-view) on multiple formsets in one view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your HTML source and you'll see that all your formsets have the same prefix. So for example, you'll have multiple input fields with the `name` attribute set to `form-0-match`, which corresponds to the `match` field of the first form (index 0) in the formset.

When using multiple formsets in a view (as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#multiple-formsets-in-view)), you need to make sure each formset has a different [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#customizing-a-formset-s-prefix).

You can set the prefix by passing the `prefix` argument to the formset initializer, e.g.:

```
formset_set = MatchSetFormset(request.POST or None, instance=match, prefix=f"form{match.pk}")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193731/discussion-on-answer-by-dirkgroten-is-this-the-good-way-to-handle-multiple-forms).